# Modified AdSense code showing at the top of my website

Tags: wordpress-theming, web-deployment, adsense, web-development-server

I'm trying to modify my google AdSense code so I can avoid invalid clicks. I'm using a plugin called "**AdSense Invalid Click protector**"

So to insert the modified AdSense code I used the **Insert Headers and Footers** plugin.

The problem is a part of my code is shown in my website header in the front end. It's totally annoying that anyone can see a code at the top of my website :/

Any suggestions for me to hide that code from being visible? Seems like the code working. But it's very ugly.....

The part visible is

```
if( aicp_can_see_ads() ) {
}
```

This is the complete code

```
    if( aicp_can_see_ads() ) { 
<div class="aicp">
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </div>
}
```